# How to call a function in regexp_replace with matches?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, parsing, plpgsql

I'd like to use some processing function instead of `replacement text` in [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function. Is it possible to use a function with matches as arguments, like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( description, '\[([is]?:?)(\d+)\]', some_custom_function(\1, \2), 'gi' ) 
  FROM some_table
  WHERE id = 123;
```

Of course, backreferences `\1` and `\2` do not work here, but is there some way to use variables instead of them?

Background: `description` may contain more than one string with a pattern like `[12345]` or `[i:12345]` or `[s:12345]` and I'd like to process such matches into advanced strings, so I thought the best way is to write a custom function and call it with matches of `regex_replace`. I just did not found in the docs, how could I use matches as variable/arguments. Is this possible or what is a better way to accomplish my goal?

Example `description` field:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [123], consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et [234] magna aliqua.
```

Desired output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "one-two-three", consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "two-three-four" magna aliqua.
```

Comment: Why not use functions for this? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createfunction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function with text argument(s), e.g.:

```
create or replace function the_function(text, text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select format('=replacement of %s and %s=', $1, $2)
$$;
```

and use it in `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(
    description, 
    '\[([is]?:?)(\d+)\]', 
    the_function('\1', '\2'), 
    'gi') 
from some_table
where id = 123;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1628ad238cc9d6e3051d875e2a0fd976)

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for. I did not figure out that is possible to quote two arguments separately. Somehow it did not click...

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Isn't `the_function` called with literally `\1` and `\2`?

Comment: @xehpuk - the syntax is important here. The lesson from this question is that you can use back references as arguments of a function in the form of **text literals.**

Comment: @klin But then the function never sees the matched values, only the string literals. What's the difference between `the_function('\1', '\2')` and `'=replacement of \1 and \2='`? How do you achieve the desired output?

Comment: @klin Adding some conversion to `the_function` (`CASE WHEN $2 = '123' THEN 'abc' ELSE $2 END`) doesn't do anything: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5b7ebf4128097473d2d914ca91b4827e

Comment: @xehpuk the implementation details of the `the_function` were not the part of the question, I just needed figure out, how to call the functions with matches

Comment: @w.k I agree. But with this solution, you don't call `the_function` with the matches. I'm surprised it worked for you.

Comment: @xehpuk You are right. I was wrong thinking that regexp_replace is a syntax exception with lazy evaluation of some arguments. It is not. It only worked because `the_function` in fact returns a constant template string `=replacement of \1 and \2=` that `regexp_replace` uses to fill the placeholders with the matched values.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_replace(description TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT string_agg(concat(l, some_custom_function(u[1], u[2])), '')
  FROM ROWS FROM (
    regexp_split_to_table(description, '\[(?:([is]):)?(\d+)\]', 'i'),
    regexp_matches(description, '\[(?:([is]):)?(\d+)\]', 'gi')
  ) AS m(l, u)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I have changed your regex from `\[([is]?:?)(\d+)\]` to `\[(?:([is]):)?(\d+)\]` so that you don't match `[i123]` or `[:123]`. This also leads to the "prefix" being `NULL` instead of `''` for matches like `[123]`. Revert to your original if this was not your intend.

Example for your custom function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_custom_function(prefix TEXT, number TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT concat((upper(prefix) || '='), CASE number
    WHEN '123' THEN '"one-two-three"'
    WHEN '234' THEN '"two-three-four"'
    ELSE CASE
      WHEN number IS NOT NULL THEN '#foo'
    END
  END)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Test with no, lowercase and uppercase "prefix":

```
SELECT unnest, my_replace(unnest)
FROM unnest(array[$$Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [123], consectetur adipiscing elit [42],
sed do eiusmod [i:123] tempor incididunt ut labore et [S:234] magna aliqua.$$])
```

The result is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "one-two-three", consectetur adipiscing elit #foo,
> sed do eiusmod I="one-two-three" tempor incididunt ut labore et S="two-three-four" magna aliqua.

Try it out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4b0e678f0e5b9a84ad46134a127a18cd)

It basically works like this:

1. Split/unzip the text into non-matches and matches.
2. Map each of them.
3. Aggregate/zip them back into a text.

Documentation for `regexp_split_to_table` and `regexp_matches`:

- [9.4. String Functions and Operators > Table 9.10. Other String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)
- [9.7. Pattern Matching > 9.7.3. POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible or what is a better way to accomplish my goal?

I'd recommend just using a [User Defined Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) for this and iterating through the characters using a parsing method rather than trying to incorporate it into a regular expression.

Below is a proof of concept to start off with. There is scope for improving this by using a table of values and their replacements instead of hard-coding them, which would be cleaner and certainly necessary if there are a lot more values - please let me know in the comments if this is required.

### SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaceDescription(description TEXT)
   RETURNS TEXT
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
DECLARE 
   pos INT := 1;
   chr CHAR;
   parsing BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
   WHILE pos <= CHAR_LENGTH(description) LOOP
      chr := SUBSTRING(description, pos, 1);
      IF chr = '[' THEN
          parsing := TRUE;
      ELSIF chr = ']' THEN
          parsing := FALSE;
      ELSIF parsing THEN
          IF chr = '1' THEN
              description := CONCAT(LEFT(description, pos - 1),
                                    'one-',
                                    RIGHT(description, CHAR_LENGTH(description) - pos));
              pos := pos + 3;
          ELSIF chr = '2' THEN
              description := CONCAT(LEFT(description, pos - 1),
                                    'two-',
                                    RIGHT(description, CHAR_LENGTH(description) - pos));
              pos := pos + 3;
          ELSIF chr = '3' THEN
              description := CONCAT(LEFT(description, pos - 1),
                                    'three-',
                                    RIGHT(description, CHAR_LENGTH(description) - pos));
              pos := pos + 5;
          ELSIF chr = '4' THEN
              description := CONCAT(LEFT(description, pos - 1),
                                    'four-',
                                    RIGHT(description, CHAR_LENGTH(description) - pos));
              pos := pos + 4;
          END IF;
      END IF;
      pos := pos + 1;
   END LOOP;
   
   RETURN REPLACE(description, '-]', ']');
END;
$$;
```

### Demo

Rextester demo: https://rextester.com/IBGE47544